# Explicit cast of pointer to long long

Tags: c, pointers

I need to cast a pointer to a long long, and would prefer to do it in a way that gcc doesn't complain on either 32 or 64-bit architectures about converting pointer to ints of different size.  And before anyone asks, yes, I know what I'm doing, and I know what I'm casting to -- my specific use case is wanting to send a stack trace (the pointers themselves being the subject here) over the network when an application error occurs, so there is no guarantee the sender and receiver will have the same word size.  I've therefore built a struct holding the message data with, among other entries, an array of "unsigned long long" values (guaranteed minimum 64-bits) to hold the pointers.  And yes, I know "long long" is not *guaranteed* to be *only* 64-bits, but all compilers I'm using for both source and destination implement it as 64-bits.  Because the header (and source) with the struct will be used on both architectures, "uintptr_t" doesn't seem like a workable solution (because, according to the definition in stdint.h, its size is architecture-dependent).

I thought about getting tricky with anonymous unions, but this feels a little too hackish to me...I'm hoping there's a way with some double-cast magic or something to do this in C99 (since anonymous unions weren't standard until C11).

EDIT:

```
typedef struct error_msg_t {
  int msgid;
  int len;
  pid_t pid;
  int si_code;
  int signum;
  int errno;
  unsigned long long stack[20];
  char err_msg[];
} error_msg_t;
...
void **stack;
...
msg.msgid = ERROR_MSG;
msg.len = sizeof(error_msg_t) + strlen(err_msg) + 1);
msg.pid = getpid();
...
for (i=0; i<stack_depth; i++)
  msg.stack[i] = (unsigned long long)stack[i];
```

Warning (on a 32-bit compile) about casting to integer of different size occurs on the last line.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: `uint64_t` would be a better choice.

Comment: `uint64_t` results the same warning.

Comment: You could disable the warning for this piece of code

Comment: Does (uint64_t)(uintptr_t)stack[1] remove the warning?

Comment: `uint_least64_t` would be even better given `uint64_t` is an optional type.

Comment: But if a pointer representation on your 32-bit architecture is only 32-bits wide (common, but not guaranteed) and you are converting it to an integer that is at least 64 bits wide, then you ***are*** converting to an `int` of a different size.  @Max's suggestion is the most likely formula for hiding that from the compiler, but disabling the warning would be a better choice than obfuscating your code that way.

Comment: But it's an int of a larger size, so there's no risk of it not being able to accurately store the value.  It's like casting a `short` to an `int`.

Comment: Might you consider sending the output of `printf("%p", ptr)` rather than an integer value?

Comment: The `uint_least64_t` is worse. The question is about integer of exact 64 bits and limited to platforms that support that. It is beneficial to get error for platform, that cannot be easily supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to double cast to spell it out to the compiler what you want to do ([as suggested by Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116545/explicit-cast-of-pointer-to-long-long#comment67505600_40116545)).

I would recommend wrapping it up into a macro so that the code intention is clear from the macro name.

```
#define PTR_TO_UINT64(x) (uint64_t)(uintptr_t)(x)
```

Comment: Don't macro what you can `static inline`.

Comment: @Rhymoid: I feel a macro is a better choice here, because while you want the code to be readable, you still want to impart the notion that something funky is happening.

Comment: Another thought I recently had was to use memcpy(), which would completely shut up the compiler since it doesn't care about the source and destination sizes or types; as long as you're passing valid pointers it's happy.

Comment: @ereisch Yes, but to deal with that additional risk of unintended corruption, you should couple that with an assertion (or static assertion) that the sizes are right.

Comment: The same can be said of any memcpy() though; I'm pretty pedantic when it comes to memset(), memcpy(), etc., and always use sizeof() the source as the third parameter, and separately ensure there's no way the destination can be overflowed.  In this case, the destination is 64-bits, so there's no way to overflow it, regardless of what architecture you're running on.
P.S. -- Also remember to always memset() the structure first, so when on a 32-bit architecture, there aren't uninitialized bytes in the destination.

Comment: Well, if the two types are exactly the same (like structs or arrays), `memcpy` is perfectly safe. When switching between types, you may suffer a curse from the future when you code has survived to when pointer types are 128 bits but `unsigned long long` remains 64. Your mileage may vary, of course.